# Features implementation issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an application that i'm working on , it's a video streaming app , the feature i'm trying to implement is playlist(collection of videos for the user to see with a unique name ).

in my associations :

```
 user => has_many playlists,
 video => belongs_to playlists,
 playlist => belongs_to user
```

ps. in my app , general user cannot create videos only admin .

after created a playlist , the user should be able to add a video to the playlist via a button . if i'm correct the playlist should be an array .and there's will a function to add _to _playlist that will retrieve the video by video_id and then push it into the array and return the final playlist.

my main issue is, i'm pretty confused on how to do the implementation.any help will be gladly appreciate.

Comment: Hey, Obed. Did you find my answer useful?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ActiveRecord and want to associate arrays with instances of your model, you should use the `serialize` class method.

From [the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :preferences
end

user = User.create(preferences: { "background" => "black", "display" => large })
User.find(user.id).preferences # => { "background" => "black", "display" => large }
```

That example uses a hash, but `serialize` also permits arrays. if you want to restrict the attribute to arrays only, you can do so like so:

```
serialize :attr, Array
```

Comment: it's resolve a part of my prob , i will give a upvote anyway.